# Awesome WM: execute my aliases via run prompt?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, environment-variables, awesome-wm

I have aliases in my bashrc for a few programs.

One example is: 
alias chrome='google-chrome --disk-cache-size=1000000000'

How can I call this alias from the run prompt (modkey+r)?

Im running linux mint

Comment: This depends of your window manager. I suggest you to place this key
information within your question.

Comment: ahem "Awesome WM: ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awful.util.spawn doesn't spawn a shell and it won't work with awful.util.spawn_with_shell because the shell has to be interactive to check for aliases.
But you could spawn a shell which executes a command in interactive mode, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_aliases
eval "$@"
```

you could also edit your ~/.xinitrc, and before the «exec awesome» add something like

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will work with startx. If you use a display manager, changes should be added in /etc/X11/Xsession.d

Either inside the awesome or the aliases scripts.

<sub>⠀</sub>
Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=118693

Comment: Excuse me for asking but what kind of changes in /etc/X11/Xsession.d? I'm not clear on what exactly I would be doing with this.

Comment: In Xsession.d there is an "aliases" script and an awesome script... Both should be called when you start awesome with a desktop manager. You add your global aliases there, or make a call to your user aliases script.